# Why file_get_contents() prepends new line?

Tags: php, ajax, file-get-contents

I have a simple PHP file which reads a file. Its code is:

```
function qOpen() {
    $fileName = $_POST['filename'];
    $contents = file_get_contents($fileName);
    return $contents;
}

$str = qOpen();
echo $str;

?>
```

I use this file from within JS file the following way:

```
        httpRequestObj.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (4 === obj.readyState) {
                var str = obj.responseText;

            }
        };
        fileName =  "/tmp/test.txt";
        res = sendAjaxPostRequest(
            httpRequestObj,
            "module_qopen.php",
            "filename=" + fileName
        );
```

Everything works, but there's a small problem. `str` somehow starts with an empty line, no matter which file I open? Where do these empty lines come from?

Comment: Yes, file starts with <?php and ends with ?>. After ?> there are empty lines. before <?php there's nothing else